# Можно ли методы Start() и Update() которые находятся скрипте вызывать в другом скрипте. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, методы

Можно ли методы Start() и Update() которые находятся скрипте вызывать в другом скрипте. Если можно почему у меня не работает? Или есть специальная для этого технология?

Я сделал так:

```
myScript.Start();
myScript.Update();
```

Comment: Найдите объект, получите экзепляр скрипта через GetComponent

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать их нельзя - у них модификатор доступа **private**.

**Start()** и **Update()** вызываются перед отображением первого кадра в сцене и каждый кадр соответственно.

Если уж так хочется вызвать какой-то код из твоего скрипта, то создай **public** метод, его уже без проблем можно вызывать в другом скрипте